# Angular2 - 'ng build -prod' results in Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

**What I'm using**

- Angular

**What I'm trying to do**

- Run the ng build -prod command

**What happens**

- I receive the following error:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

- This error doesn't exist when running 'ng build --watch'

**What i've tried**

- I've removed some of my HTML that includes a submit button to pass some values through to a function in my component typescript file. When i do this, the build command works fine.

**Component HTML**

Below is the HTML snippet that's causing the issue. I'm taking values from input fields and pushing them through to a function. When running 'ng build -watch', i have no issues whatsoever, everything works. Only on the 'prod' command do I receive the error in the terminal

```html
      <div class="vs__details__actions">
        <button class="vs__button" 
        [disabled]="!selectedFiles" 
        (click)="submitForm(newTitle.value, newReference.value, newDate.value, newAuditorName.value, newCompanyName.value); newTitle.value=''; 
        newReference.value=''; newDate.value=''; newAuditorName.value=''; newCompanyName.value=''"> 
        Add 
      </button>
      </div>
```

**Component Typescript file**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectsAddService } from './projects-add.service';
import { Upload } from './upload';
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'upload-form',
  templateUrl: './projects-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects-add.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsAddComponent {

  selectedFiles: FileList;
  currentUpload: Upload;

  constructor(private upSvc: ProjectsAddService) { }

  detectFiles(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  }

  uploadSingle() {
    let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0)
    this.currentUpload = new Upload(file);
  }

  submitForm(title: string, reference: string, date: string, auditorName: string, newCompanyName: string, upload: Upload) {
    let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0)
    this.currentUpload = new Upload(file);
    this.upSvc.submitForm(title, reference, date, auditorName, newCompanyName, this.currentUpload);
  }


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What is the (click) function? Have you checked the indentation? Is that a typo or is it really like this?

Comment: The click is how i pass in the new input values to the function in the component.ts. As for the indentation, that's stackoverflow. I couldn't squeeze that in neatly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `--prod` (production mode) angular-cli will use AoT (Ahead of Time compilation).

AoT is a bit more sensible about types, signatures and stuff.

your `submitForm` function expects a (not optional) `upload: Upload` argument as last parameter, which you don't pass on click.

Two options here:

First (and suggested) way: Make it optional like `submitForm(title: string, reference: string, date: string, auditorName: string, newCompanyName: string, upload?: Upload)`

Alternative: pass `null` at the last argument in your template.

Hope it helps.

---

Update: After your edit of your question and your comment, i should probably just add the third option here: Just remove the param, if it's not used in your function.

Comment: ah gotcha. Upload is actually from the typescript file which is why it's not referenced in the HTML as it's not something I need to pass in from the HTML. I've updated my code to show the full typescript file. What's the best option in this case?

Comment: If you don't need to pass it in (like ever) why did you declare it as a param? just remove it.

Comment: Apologies, maybe I wasn't clear. I'm calling an upload service which requires all the new input values from the html AND the upload. However the upload is from the component ts file, not the html. My above comment is stating that I don't / can't pass the upload from the HTML which is why it's the TS file only. As you said, that means the submit button as 5 params but the ts function as 6. But it needs 6. This is where I'm now stuck.

Comment: Why? You are not using the param therefore you don't need it. In your components `submitForm` function you call another function with the same name, but that's in your service, not in your component. And you don't pass the `upload` Object from your function, you pass the referene of `currentUpload` of your component. So no, you don't need 6 there, you need only the first 5.

Comment: Jesus christ...you're right. How was i so blind to that?! I've be staring at it to long. Lexith good sir, thank you for your patience!

Comment: Hehe we all are in these situations sometime. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your submit forms requires 6 parameters and you're calling that function with 5 values in your template. 
You're missing the value for "upload".